# Is it possible to plot two variables using a third one as filter in R?

Tags: r, variables, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot using two variables (`DATE` and `INT_RATE`) using for **filter** the content of a third variable `GRADE`.
The problem is that I can't really figure out how to use the variable `GRADE` as a filter for the row.

In the below section i provide a detailed sample of starting data as well as draw of the plot I'm trying to achieve.
Thanks in advance.

```
 STARTING DATA     

 | DATE  | INT_RATE | GRADE |
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
 | 1-jan | 5%       | A     | <-- A
 | 5-feb | 3%       | B     |
 | 9-feb | 2%       | D     |
 | 1-apr | 3%       | A     | <-- A
 | 5-jun | 5%       | A     | <-- A
 | 1-aug | 3%       | G     |
 | 1-sep | 2%       | E     |
 | 3-nov | 1%       | C     |
 | 8-dec | 8%       | A     | <-- A
 |   .   | .        | .     |
 |   .   | .        | .     |
 |   .   | .        | .     |
```

And this is the kind of graph i would like to achieve, which is a very basic one, except for the filtering work needed before.

```
WANTED RESULT:

GRADE "A"

   INT_RATE
       |
       |
    8%-|                            •   
       |                           ̷
       |                        ̷ 
       |                     ̷
    5%-|  •              •
       |   \            /
       |     \        /
       |       \     /
       |         \ /
    3%-|          •
       |
       |  
       |
       |
    ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––-–––>
       |  ˆ       ˆ      ˆ           ˆ   DATE
       |1-jan   1-apr   5-jun      8-dec
```

**EDIT 1:**

Following the precious help from @apax I managed to get a plot, but the result is not satisfying because of the weird way R is displaying it (I think it might be related to the fact that the dataset in question is very large 800k rows). Do you have any suggestion?

[image: malformed graph]

By the way, this solved my problem:

```
plot(x = DATE, y = INT_RATE, data =  filter(df, GRADE == "A"))
```

I am also uploading a PNG of the malformed chart.
Thanks again to all.

Comment: I see you accepted an answer and edited your post to ask a new question. If you're interested in responses to the second question, it is best to ask in a new post rather than editing your current post. Note that in order to help as many users as possible, your post is given a single title, the scope of your problem is bounded, and you can only accept a single answer - i.e., when other users encounter the same kind of problem, they might come across this post. A question-answer buried in the comments is not going to achieve this.

Comment: @CPak thanks a lot for the suggestion. You have been very kind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick one-liner solution where I assume your data is stored in an object named `df`

```
library(dplyr) ## For filter() function below

plot(x = DATE, y = INT_RATE, data =  filter(df, GRADE == "A"))
```

Comment: Or base R's `by`: `by(df, df$GRADE, function(d) plot(DATE, INT_RATE, d))`

Comment: @apax your solutions works just fine except for the fact that DATA on the X axis is inexplicably not in order. Do you maybe know the reason?

Comment: @scugn1zz0 my understanding of your question is that you're asking how to sort your data.  Have a look at this relevant stack overflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns)

Comment: @apax thanks a lot, i managed to solve, the problem was that the date was not interpreted from R correctly i had to do as follows:

`df$DATE <- as.Date(gsub("^", "01-", df$DATE), format="%d-%b-%Y")`

Comment: @apax I uploaded the graph I am obtaining, do you maybe know a way to improve it?

Comment: @scugn1zz0 At this point you should probably re-post your graphing question to specifically ask about the formatting of your graph as this post's original question has been answered here.  As a heads up, you may not get helpful responses without posting a minimal, reproducible example.  So be prepared for that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ggplot2` and `facet_wrap(...)`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

For your data

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=DATE, y=INT_RATE)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~GRADE)
```

> P.S. This gives separate graphs for all grades. But that should not be a problem.