# How to improve a scatter plot for plotting a large dataset in R?

Tags: r, database, plot, bigdata, scatter-plot

I am trying to create a plot using two variables (`DATE` and `INT_RATE`) using as filter the content of a third variable called `GRADE`.

In the following section there is a sample of the **very large data set** I'm processing as well as the result I am obtaining.

```
 STARTING DATA     

 | DATE  | INT_RATE | GRADE |
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
 | 1-jan | 5%       | A     | <-- A
 | 5-feb | 3%       | B     |
 | 9-feb | 2%       | D     |
 | 1-apr | 3%       | A     | <-- A
 | 5-jun | 5%       | A     | <-- A
 | 1-aug | 3%       | G     |
 | 1-sep | 2%       | E     |
 | 3-nov | 1%       | C     |
 | 8-dec | 8%       | A     | <-- A
 |   .   | .        | .     |
 |   .   | .        | .     |
 |   .   | .        | .     |
```

And this is the kind of graph i would like to achieve.

```
WANTED RESULT:

GRADE "A"

   INT_RATE
       |
       |
    8%-|                            •   
       |                           ̷
       |                        ̷ 
       |                     ̷
    5%-|  •              •
       |   \            /
       |     \        /
       |       \     /
       |         \ /
    3%-|          •
       |
       |  
       |
       |
    ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––-–––>
       |  ˆ       ˆ      ˆ           ˆ   DATE
       |1-jan   1-apr   5-jun      8-dec
```

**This is the relevant section of my R script that I used to build the graph shown below** (the `filter` function is used to filter data):

```
plot(x = df$issue_d, y = df$int_rate, data=filter(df, df$grade == "A"))
```

And this is the "broken" graph I'm obtaining:

[image: malformed graph]

**NOW THE QUESTION**

How can I improve this graph? Because reading it in this way is just not possible, maybe I should go for a whole different kind of graph, but which one? I **do** need to filter data before plotting them.

Comment: Few moments ago you asked a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49903606/1315767)

Comment: @JilberUrbina the question is now a very different one, and I'm asking a new question as suggested by "apax" and "CPak"